# R - Search multiple columns with same conditions and count rows by column and condition

Tags: r

My problem may be best explained through three questions.

1). Is there a way of searching across multiple columns using indices (I use column names in the example below) using the same conditions? I'm wondering if there's a more elegant way of implementing this (I have another approach below)?

```
sepsis <- subset(allhospitals, diag_p %in% c(78552, 99592) | 
                 odiag1 %in% c(78552, 99592) | 
                 odiag2 %in% c(78552, 99592) |  
                 odiag3 %in% c(78552, 99592) |
                 ## etc. etc.
```

2.) After I've subset my data, I'd like to count the number of rows where both conditions are present for each column (i.e. how many times 78552 and 99552 occur in diag_p, odiag1, odiag2, etc.).

3.) Lastly, I'd like to do the calculation above and slice it by factors from another column.

My strategy (which is awful) has been to: 
a.) create vector of column indices; then 
b.) apply a two functions (one for each condition) to subset the data and count rows; 
c.) make a new data frame (one for each condition) with the column indices as the only column; and finally
d.) use 'apply' with the function I wrote upon the column indices (i.e. the new data frame's only column).

```
## indices for all columns of interest
ind <- c(35, seq(from=39, to=85, by=2)) 

## create one data frame and function per ICD-9 code (i.e., condition)
f7 <- function(x) nrow(subset(allhospitals, allhospitals[x]=="78552"))
t.7 <- data.frame("diag"=ind)
t.7$freq <- apply(t.7,1,f7)

f9 <- function(x) nrow(subset(allhospitals, allhospitals[x]=="99592"))
t.9 <- data.frame("diag"=ind)
t.9$freq <- apply(t.9,1,f9)
```

Then I'll rbind all this and get an aggregate value for my entire dataset. The problem is that I need to do this for several individual factors, thus rendering my approach above very tedious. All attempts with the plyr package have been fruitless, though I'm rather new to R so perhaps there's a solution here, too.

UPDATE:

I tried the plyr package again and got something close to what I want, though I have to do it one condition ("99592") and one column ("odiag1") at a time since I need to get row counts by each condition -- not for all conditions combined. As you can see, my code still looks ugly. At any rate, I get back a data frame that I have to reshape into a 'long' format, since my dataset is so wide and tough to work with. Here's some representative data and my updated ddply approach:

Sample data:

```
    id  patzip  adm_yr  diag_p  odiag1 odiag2  odiag3  odiag4  etc.  etc.  etc.
Hosp A   93077    2010   99592   16932  22107   78552      NA
Hosp B   99804    2011   16932   99592  78552   12988      NA
Hosp B   94503    2010   22107   78552  12988   99592   16932
Hosp A   93013    2010   12988   22107  12988      NA      NA
Hosp C   93112    2009   99592   78552  22107      NA      NA
```

My new approach:

```
library(plyr)
df <- ddply(allhospital, .(id), summarize, diag_p = length(id[diag_p == 99592]), 
        odiag1 = length(id[odiag1 == 99592]), odiag2 = length(id[odiag2 == 99592]),
        odiag3 = length(id[odiag3 == 99592]), odiag4 = length(id[odiag4 == 99592]),
        odiag5 = length(id[odiag5 == 99592]), odiag6 = length(id[odiag6 == 99592]),
        odiag7 = length(id[odiag7 == 99592]), odiag8 = length(id[odiag8 == 99592]),
        odiag9 = length(id[odiag9 == 99592]), odiag10 = length(id[odiag10 == 99592]),
        odiag11 = length(id[odiag11 == 99592]), odiag12 = length(id[odiag12 == 99592]),
        odiag13 = length(id[odiag13 == 99592]), odiag14 = length(id[odiag14 == 99592]),
        odiag15 = length(id[odiag15 == 99592]), odiag16 = length(id[odiag16 == 99592]),
        odiag17 = length(id[odiag17 == 99592]), odiag18 = length(id[odiag18 == 99592]),
        odiag19 = length(id[odiag19 == 99592]), odiag20 = length(id[odiag20 == 99592]),
        odiag21 = length(id[odiag21 == 99592]), odiag22 = length(id[odiag22 == 99592]),
        odiag23 = length(id[odiag23 == 99592]), odiag24 = length(id[odiag24 == 99592]))
```

UPDATE 2:

Here's one way the expected result could look:

```
    id     diag  Count.78552  Count.99552
Hosp A   diag_p            4            0
Hosp A   odiag1           10            8
Hosp A   odiag2           17           16
Hosp A   odiag3            9           10
Hosp B   diag_p            5            8
Hosp B   odiag1            1            3
Hosp B   odiag2            0            1
Hosp B   odiag3            0            0
```

Comment: Please add representative data.

Answer (score 0):

The same condition for several columns.

```
vn_cond <- c("diag_p","odiag1","odiag2","odiag3")# columns to meet condition
cond_set <- c(78552, 99592)# values in condition set
#
# sapply - repeats conditions 
# rowSums(...)>0 - at least one TRUE in row
#
sepsis <- allhospitals[rowSums(sapply(allhospitals[vn_cond],
                                      "%in%", cond_set))>0,]
```

Edit

```
require(reshape2)

hosp_long <- melt(allhospitals[c("id",vn_cond)],
                  id.vars="id", na.rm=TRUE,
                  variable.name="var_diag")
hosp_long <- transform(hosp_long,diag_78552 = 0L+(value == 78552),
                                 diag_99592 = 0L+(value == 99592))
hosp_long <- melt(subset(hosp_long,select=-value), id.vars=c("id","var_diag"),
                  variable.name="var_cond")
out <- dcast(hosp_long, id+var_diag~var_cond, sum)
```

Comment: Your answer addresses my first question regarding a more elegant way of subsetting. Any thoughts about aggregating column data (counting rows, essentially) by individual condition and by hospital (or some other factor)?

Comment: In second question, your condition is not clear to me. I think you should present expected result for your sample data.

Comment: The conditions in my example are the codes 99592 and 78552. My goal is to count the occurrence of these within my desired columns and sort by hospital. I'be added a sample output, too (with dummy data).

Comment: I was afraid my problem would have lengthy solution. Is there a better way of displaying the final data (e.g., having three columns instead of four in the data frame - id, diag, and condition)? Really appreciate your help!

Comment: I get the following error at `hosp_long <- transform` --> `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'value' not found`